# How to find the width and height of an image with quil in clojure

Tags: clojure, processing, quil

I am trying to find the width of a loaded image in clojure. In processing I would do this,

```
    PImage img=loadImage("image.jpg");
    int x=img.width;
    int y=img.height;
```

I tried to do this same in clojure but it won't work

```
   (defn loadwebimg []
     (let [filelst (map (fn [f] (.getName f)) (.listFiles (File. (str datadir))))
           imgf (first (shuffle filelst))
           webimg (load-image (str datadir imgf))
           ]
      (image webimg 0 0) 
      (println webimg.height))
```

Comment: Jake, can you say more about the symptom?  Was there an error message? Did the error message have a line number?

Comment: The first problem I see is how you're calling println.  You need to do this: `(println (.height webimg))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If webimg is an object when you would use the `.` special form to read its fields like you do for the file objects you use above it.

as user100464 points out:

```
(println webimg.height)
```

would become

```
(println (. webimg height)
```

or

```
(println (.height webimg))
```